# Cover only directly called code from test function in pytest coverage

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py, pytest-cov

I need to cover only code that is called directly from test function, every nested method call must be marked as missed. This must help me ensure that every unit/method has his own test.

Example: test function calls method A and method A calls method B inside. After that I want to have A method marked as covered and method B marked as missed, as it was not directly called from test function.

Does anybody know plugin or has any idea how to do that?

I have tried googling and reading coverage docs, the only thing slightly related is dynamic contexts, but they show which methods called the line. This differs from what I want, because in this case I must check every line caller method. I just want this lines(that are not called directly) to be marked red.

Answer (score 0):

Coverage.py doesn't have a way to do this.  There's discussion about marking which product functions are intended to be covered by each test as a possible future feature: https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/696